# Why state verbs are seen as not having any definite beginning or end?

Tags: stative-verbs

[People say:](http://flesl.net/Grammar/Grammar_Glossary/eventVerb_stateVerb.php)

> • English verbs can be placed in various classes depending on their
>   meaning. In other words, they can be classified “semantically.” The
>   most important of these classes are: event verbs and state verbs.
>
> • **Event verbs** refer to events—happenings that begin and end at a
>   definite time. For example, the verb build as it is used in the
>   sentence Jack built a beautiful house by the beach is an event verb.
>
> • **State verbs** refer to states—conditions or situations that are seen
>   as **not having any definite beginning or end**; they are seen as
>   permanent, in other words. For example, the verb own as it is used in
>   the sentence Jack owns a beautiful house by the beach is a state verb.

**Why state verbs are seen as not having any definite beginning or end?**

Now see this sentence "**I am at home**" ("**to be**" is a state verb in this case). And, if you have a good watch, you can pinpoint the precise time you enter your house & the precise time you walk out of your house.

Another example, "**I see her! I see her!**" ("**to see**" is a state verb in this case). If you have someone watch your behavior, that person can define the specific time that you **start** seeing her & the time you **stop** seeing her.

Comment: It's true that the state which a stative verb names will ordinarily have a beginning and an end &mdash; but neither the beginning nor the end is ***included in the sense of the verb***.

Comment: Answered (with clarification) at [Is “attempt” a durative or a punctual verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95162/is-attempt-a-durative-or-a-punctual-verb) (where telicity is addressed).

Answer (score 0):

> **TL;DR** *(summary of my longer answer)*
>   State verbs do not imply permanence, they simply omit any mention of (im)permanence due to its irrelevance in the current context.

---

I think this is a wrong interpretation of state verbs.

State verbs are not implied to have a definitive end and beginning, not because the state of things is provably permanent, but rather that **their (lack of) permanence isn't relevant to the message that is currently being conveyed**. The acknowledgement of beginning and ending is omitted as it is irrelevant in the current context.

**State** verbs have a very specific meaning: making a **statement**.

> Jack owns a house

The intention of this sentence is to confirm **that** Jack owns a house (stating it as a fact, which was not yet known by the other person); rather than trying to imply **how long** he will own (or has owned) this house.

This sentence does not imply that Jack will own this house for eternity; it simply **omits** any acknowledgement of the temporariness of the ownership.

Comment: Whom are you quoting in that opening quotation block? And is the pronouncement (complete with comma splice) that follows the ever-rude "TL;DR" itself the "wrong interpretation" that you are disagreeing with in the following sentence?

Comment: @BrianDonovan: **TL;DR** can be used as a statement, meaning "I didn't read this, it is too long". However, it can also be used to denote a summary, specifically added for those who might feel that the full answer is too long. [See here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TLDR), the second definition of the initialism (although I'm not sure about the non-sequitur. I would expect a non-sequitur to simply be a comical subversion of an accurate summary). I am therefore not quoting anyone, this is a (non-rude) summary I have written. Your downvote seems a bit unwarranted here, if I may say.

Comment: @BrianDonovan: Nonetheless, I have updated my answer to prevent any further confusion.